# grep command in Unix and Linux to list the number of occurrences of a word in a file

Tags: unix

what is the Unix and Linux command to list the number of occurrences of a word in a file?

I did not get the results I was looking for using `grep -c 'word' <file name>`

I would like to display:

```
word
word
word
```

and the number 3

Comment: look for "wc -w"

Comment: what is the complete command? grep -c 'word' <file> | wc -w   ?

Comment: grep -ri "word" <file> | wc -w

Comment: grep -ow  'word' <file> | tee >(wc -w)  use this in case you want list of word to be printed too

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `word` shows up at most once per line (or you don't care), you can do it with a simple pipe:

`grep word file | wc -l`